# Setting up a java GUI building and rooms

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm looking for advice and ideas from more experienced programmers.

What I'm trying to do is create the layout of one of the floors of my school building, with all the rooms and such in place, and then have "people" walking around like a simulation of the day (think of the Marauder's Map from Harry Potter).

What I really want to know is how I would set everything up to actually make a 2D version of the floor and keep the dots representing people from going through walls, and make them actually go to classes based on their schedules.

I've already sort of thought about trying the A* algorithm and using nodes to make people move, but I don't know how effective this will be, and how I would create the walls and doorways for people to pass through.

Does anyone have any ideas or advice on approaching this?

EDIT:: Another quick question. How would I make the people move in order to go to classes and such? Especially if A* isn't the best idea for that.

Comment: This is a pretty complicated question, and probably more than a single answer can cover...

Comment: There are a number of choices based on what you want to achieve. You could generate a pre-rendered view of the area (using a image created in Photoshop for example) which would act as the bases for main view.  You could then create a mask (black and white for example) which defined the areas that the people could move in. You would use the mask to determine if a given pixel is white or black and determine how to react to those changes.  This creates a rather `static` environment, meaning that it might be difficult to scale the map

Comment: The mask idea sounds great! Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Another choice might be to use the 2D Graphics API of Java and generate a floor plan using some kind of `Shape`.  You could produce a rather complex polygon for example, which you could then transform as you see fit to meet the size of the output you want.  This would allow you to use the `Shape`'s API to determine if content falls within the area or not and make determinations about movement.

Comment: I've done something similar using `java.awt.geom.SimpleLine` to represent walls, and having actors move through the map and use some simple math to keep them from walking through walls. Check it out here: [ai-simulation:old-ai-sim-complexeyes](https://github.com/ProgrammerDan/ai-simulation/blob/old-ai-sim-complexeyes/src/main/java/com/programmerdan/ai/maze/SimulationMap.java). Clearly the code there might be a bit complex for your purposes, but feel free to fork. This allows a more dynamic solution that a mask, but a mask is also a great solution that I've used in other situations.

Answer (score 2):

### You Could...

Create a bit map representing the floor plan, this is what would be displayed on the screen.  You would then create a mask of the floor plan, which defines the areas which an actor can move.

The mask would basically represent a core color which the actor could move on, when moving, you would be checking the pixels around the actor to determine the actor can move in the direction they want, for example

Floor Plan:
[image: Floor]
Mask:
[image: Mask]

The first image would be what's displayed on the screen, the mask would be used to determine if a given x/y position represents a movable pixel position (ie black).  I've also included different door types, but that's up to you.

The problem with this approach is that it's not very scalable, as want you mask not to contain any anti-aliasing, you deliberately want it to be rough around the edges.

### You Could...

Use the 2D graphics API within Java to generate a polygon of some kind.  Personally I would use some kind of `Shape`, like `Path2D` for example.  This could read it's information from a file or simply be hard coded.

This would then allow you to use the available API functionality to make determinations about whether a point is contained within the shape with ease (`Shape#contains`)

This approach would allow you to apply a transformation to the shape, which could be easily painted and translated on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas:

- Don't use a path finding algorithm for moving people. You will likely have a picture (jpg/png) background for the floor-plan. Instead
- Use predetermined paths, if your floor plan seems to be a static one. Maybe add some randomness to the paths.
- Your main problem seems to be one of graphics manipulation, in particular moving components. A null layout prevents any layout-manager from interfering.
- The predetermined paths can be encoded in an image (as per MadProgrammers suggestion), in that case the movement logic will dictate how to use that information.